# Django Child template not loading the form

Tags: django

I have a base Django template:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'CS/base.css' %}">

    </head>
    <body>
        


        <header class="site-header">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-steel fixed-top">
              <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand mr-4" href="/">Cheat Sheet</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggle" aria-controls="navbarToggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggle">
                  <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'CS-home' %}">Home</a>
                <!--    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="">About</a>  -->
                  </div>
                  <!-- Navbar Right Side -->
                  <div class="navbar-nav">
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Register</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </nav>
          </header>
          {% block body %}
          {% endblock body %}




        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     
    </body>
</html>
```

And a Child Template home.html:

```
{% extends "CS/base.html" %}
{% block body %} {% endblock body %}
{% block content %}

    <div class="container">
    <form action="/URL/" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

And my views.py function to load the home.html file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import urlForm
# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    context={}
    context['form']=urlForm
    return render(request,'CS/home.html',context)
```

And finally, the form class:

```
from django import forms

class urlForm(forms.Form):
    URL=forms.CharField(label='Url')
```

When I try to render the form in the child template while including the base template, the form does not render, however, when I remove the `{% extends "CS/base.html" %}` , the form does render, I am not sure why the form renders when the include for the base template is removed.
I tried also checking the page source to see if the form was hidden behind another element and it wasn't. Lastly, I have checked all the imports twice and have made sure that the app is included in the settings, also, here is the tree structure for the files:

```
.
├── CS
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── admin.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── apps.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── forms.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── models.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   └── views.cpython-38.pyc
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   │       └── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── static
│   │   └── CS
│   │       └── base.css
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── CS
│   │       ├── base.html
│   │       └── home.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
└── mysite
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
    │   ├── settings.cpython-38.pyc
    │   ├── urls.cpython-38.pyc
    │   └── wsgi.cpython-38.pyc
    ├── asgi.py
    ├── settings.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── wsgi.py
```

Comment: It's `{% block body %}` that should contain your content. `{% block content %}` does not exist on your base template so does not get inserted anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `{% block body %}` tag from base.html

**base.html**

```
      {% block content %}
      {% endblock %}
```

**home.html**

```
{% extends "CS/base.html" %}
{% block content %}

    <div class="container">
    <form action="/URL/" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at your template tags: you have `{% block body %}{% endblock body %}` in your parent template but your form is inside `{% block content %}{% endblock content %}` in your child template while the `body` block is empty. Move your form in the `body` block.

Comment: Ahh thank you, that did the trick, should I keep my.    ```{% block content %}{% endblock content %}```        in If I do not plan on reusing the form on any other pages?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking, the block content where?